# Can you Create Tags on AWS ECR Repositories via Cloud Formation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, tagging, amazon-ecr

I have tags assigned to the CF Stack and assigned to the ECR Repository resource at the resource level in the CF template. Neither of which are getting assigned on the ECR Repository once created.

Can anyone confirm that they have Tags working for ECR Repositories via CF? If so, this is must be a problem my end.

Region: eu-west-1

**Note** - I am not referring to docker image tags. This is AWS Tags on the ECR Repo.

Comment: I believe that should work (famous last words) and looking at their public roadmap* I don't see it flagged … maybe raise it there? *) https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this turned out to be missing permissions. The reason I missed this for so long is that Cloudformation doesn't create any errors. It just doesn't create the tags.

Ensure you have the necessary permissions to create Tags for ECR Repositories.

```
ecr:TagResource    
ecr:UntagResource
```

Answer (score 4):

Tags on the ECR repository are supported and worked right away in my case.

Here an excerpt of my CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'ecr repo'
Resources:
  ECR:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: tagKey
          Value: tag1
        - Key: tagKey2
          Value: tag2
      RepositoryName: "ecr1"
```

Now I instantiated the template with a stack tag, which also was applied to the repository.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name ecr \
      --template-body file://ecr.yml \
      --tags Key=StackTag,Value=tag99
```

Here the screenshot from the ECR console.
[image: AWS console - ECR]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond @jens walter. Your answer forced me to fully investigate this. In short it turned out to be permissions. See my answer below.